# Get the description of a ES6 Symbol

Tags: javascript, symbols, ecmascript-6

I wonder if there is a nice way to get the descriptions of a Symbol.

For example,

```
var s = Symbol(5);
```

The default implementation of the toString will simply print 
    Symbol(5)

I would like to find a way to extract the actual description i.e. 5

Comment: can use regex : `/^Symbol\((.+?)\)$/.exec("Symbol(5)");` or slice : `"Symbol(5)".slice(7,-1);`

Comment: Thanks for you comment. That's basically what I ended up doing. But i thought there is a predefined API for that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this? There isn't an exposed API because you shouldn't really be accessing that value at all. It's only really there for debugging purposes.

Comment: I want to apply the concept of Enums using Symbols to achieve uniqueness.

Comment: closely related: [Can I rely on the string representation of an ES6 `Symbol`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33595946/1048572)

Comment: Similar example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189471/how-can-i-obtain-symbol-names-literals

Answer (score 16):

[`Symbol.description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description) returns description of the symbol.
Simply do `s.description` in your case.

Comment: This is the right answer, and it works great in very modern environments, but note that this is still very new, and isn't supported in even the current node LTS release yet (10.15.3).

Comment: @TimPerry is right, Node still doesn't have support for Symbol.description. 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description#Browser_compatibility].

However, as a work around you write a helper function like this.  
`private resolveSymbol(symbol: Symbol): string {   
    const regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;  
    const names = regExp.exec(symbol.toString()) || [];  
    return names[1];  
  }  
`

Comment: @Rushipatel This doesn’t work for `Symbol(")")` and `Symbol("")`. Please don’t use regex to get the description. Use `String(symbol).slice(7, -1)` instead, but note that only the real `Symbol.prototype.description` can distinguish `Symbol()` from `Symbol("")`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no neat way to do this. However, if you have registered a symbol in the global registry, you can use [`Symbol.keyFor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/keyFor):

```
var s = Symbol.for(5);
console.log(Symbol.keyFor(s));
```

Comment: Thanks! that will work also with "older" node 10, where `Symbol.prototype.description` isn't supported

Answer (score 1):

```
 String(symbol).slice(7, -1) || null
```

This works because `String(symbol)` explicitly coerce the symbol into a string e.g. `Symbol('test')` gets coerced into `"Symbol(test)"`.

Doing a splicing on the from 7 to -1 does a splicing between the two brackets, thus capturing the description `test`

**Note**: that this may not work for object descriptions (e.g. `Symbol({test})`) as objects gets coerced into `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please add some explanation as to how/why this answers the question?

Comment: There are no symbols with object descriptions, the description is always cast to a string.

Answer (score -7):

## [`symbol-description`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/symbol-description) package on npm

Returns description of provided symbol:

```
const symDesc = require('symbol-description')
symDesc(Symbol('foo')) // foo
```

It was published by me just now after reading [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35832072/359072).

Comment: So you created an npm package for one line of code?

Comment: I did it for you.