# Can I rely on the string representation of an ES6 `Symbol`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

I'm working on an ES6 app that sends some of its data over the network. Part of this involves identifiers that are implemented as ES6 `Symbol`s. For example:

```
const FOO = Symbol('foo');
```

Calling `Foo.toString()` yields `Symbol(foo)`. When I pass these over the network, I'd like to pass it as just `foo`. However, to my knowledge, there is no way to extract `foo` from `Symbol(foo)` other than to pull it out with a regular expression (specifically, `/^Symbol\((.*)\)$/`).

**Should I rely on the regular expression always matching?** Or is it possible that future updates to ES6 will break this? If I can't rely on the regex matching then I'll just send it over the wire as `Symbol(foo)`.

Comment: Which regular expression would you propose?

Comment: Proposing `/^Symbol\((.*)\)$/` (then using the first capture group as the name). Added to question.

Comment: According to the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring) it’s always `"Symbol(" + description + ")"`. You’re probably better off using `FOO.toString().slice(7, -1)`, because a symbol description could itself contain parentheses, line breaks, etc. The `.` doesn’t match line breaks for example.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-symbol.prototype.tostring) it’s always `"Symbol(" + description + ")"`.

`Symbol.prototype.toString` returns a string from an internal method call to `SymbolDescriptiveString(sym)`:

> Let *desc* be *sym*’s `[[Description]]` value.
>   If *desc* is `undefined`, let *desc* be the empty string.
>   […]
>   Return the string-concatenation of `"Symbol("`, *desc*, and `")"`.

Now, updating this answer in 2019, you have two options:

1. Use (or polyfill) [`Symbol.prototype.description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description), which is [part of ECMAScript 2019](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-symbol.prototype.description) and is supported by all modern JavaScript engines:

   ```js
   const foo = Symbol("foo"),
     bar = Symbol.for("bar"),
     iter = Symbol.iterator;

   console.log(foo.description); // "foo"
   console.log(bar.description); // "bar"
   console.log(Symbol.iterator.description); // "Symbol.iterator"
   ```
2. Or use `Symbol.prototype.toString` like so:

   ```js
   const foo = Symbol("foo"),
     bar = Symbol.for("bar"),
     iter = Symbol.iterator;

   console.log(foo.toString().slice(7, -1)); // "foo"
   console.log(bar.toString().slice(7, -1)); // "bar"
   console.log(iter.toString().slice(7, -1)); // "Symbol.iterator"

   // Or without “magic numbers”:
   console.log(foo.toString().slice("Symbol(".length, -")".length)); // "foo"
   console.log(bar.toString().slice("Symbol(".length, -")".length)); // "bar"
   console.log(iter.toString().slice("Symbol(".length, -")".length)); // "Symbol.iterator"
   ```

Since the strings surrounding the description are fixed, `slice` is a good option to use, especially because a symbol description could itself contain parentheses, line breaks, the string `"Symbol"`, etc, and the `.` in the regular expression won’t match line breaks for example.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing to add to @Xufox' answer is that `Symbol.prototype.toString` could be compromised (overwritten), in which case it might return something else. Given that that's hardly a scenario you'll want/need to consider, it should be fine; go for `.toString().slice(7, -1);`.

---

An alternative solution you might want to consider would be to use a global symbol. If you are going to pass your data around, and will require to prevent name collisions anyway, this would be a suitable use case (assuming you're not writing a library that's supposed to be used by third parties).

You'd use

```
const FOO = Symbol.for("foo");
//                 ^^^
```

and could then get the symbol's name (which is also its description) back through

```
Symbol.keyFor(FOO) // "foo"
```

Comment: This is fine but wouldn't work if you have to have separate symbols with their description set as "foo" since all assignments made by `Symbol.for("foo")` will assign the same symbol.

Comment: @Redu That's the point of them being global, yes. You will need to choose `foo` carefully.