# How can I obtain Symbol names (literals)?

Tags: javascript, symbols

Following situation:

```
var myVehicle = { brand: 'Tesla' };

var isMoving = Symbol();
var currentStatus = Symbol();

myVehicle[isMoving] = true;
myVehicle[currentStatus] = 'moving';
```

I want to print the names of used "Symbol-properties" in my object `myVehicle`

```
console.log(
    myVehicle[isMoving],  // true
    myVehicle[currentStatus],  // 'moving',
    Reflect.ownKeys(myVehicle),  // [ 'brand', Symbol(), Symbol() ]
    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myVehicle), // [ Symbol(), Symbol() ]
);
```

How can I get the names like:

`[isMoving, currentStatus]` instead of `[ Symbol(), Symbol() ]`

**Solution**

No names, but descriptions:

```js
var myVehicle = { brand: 'Tesla' };

var isMoving = Symbol('isMoving');
var currentStatus = Symbol('currentStatus');

myVehicle[isMoving] = true;
myVehicle[currentStatus] = 'moving';

Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(myVehicle).forEach((sym, index) =>
  console.log(
    index + 1 + '. Symbol Description: ',
    sym.description + ': ',
    myVehicle[sym],
  ),
);
```

Outputs:

```
1. Symbol Description:  isMoving:  true
2. Symbol Description:  currentStatus:  moving
```

Comment: why not take the name as value instead of a symbolic rereference to an internal value, which is not readable.

Comment: Hi @Nina, in the real use case it is not a such of object, it is a div-box, that currently moves, I have used a short (maybe meaningless) example,.. All I have to know is: how can I get the names,..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you're having problems is that Javascript symbols don't have "names", exactly.

### symbols don't really have names

When you assign a symbol to a variable, that does **not** give the symbol a name that follows it around.
For instance, consider this code:

```
function getMeASymbol() {
  var alpha = Symbol()
  var beta = alpha
  return beta
}

var gamma = getMeASymbol()
```

Inside the function we create a symbol and store it in `alpha`.
Then we store the same symbol in `beta`.
Finally, we return the symbol and the caller stores it in `gamma`.
None of those three variable names is really attached to the symbol.
What's more, `alpha` and `beta` don't even exist by the time `gamma` is assigned.

### symbols do have descriptions

If you pass in a description when you create a symbol, it keeps that string around for information purposes.
You might consider that the symbol's "name", although those "names" aren't necessarily unique.
Later, you can see the description inside the return value of the symbol's `.toString()` method.

```
console.log(Symbol('mySymbol').toString()) // prints "Symbol(mySymbol)"
```

If you want to get just the original description, you can strip off the extra stuff:

```
console.log(Symbol('mySymbol').toString().slice(7,-1))
```

*update* Symbols now have a [`.description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description) property you can use instead of calling `toString` and stripping off the extra characters.

```
console.log(Symbol('mySymbol').description)
```

### conclusion

- A variable has a name.
- A variable will point to a value.
- A symbol is a kind of value.
- But a value does not point back at any of the variables that contain it.
- So you can't get a variable name from a value.
- But if you want something useful to look at when you're debugging, give your symbols descriptions.

Comment: .description!!! fantastic note. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn't really make sense. Those *variable* names have nothing really to do with the Symbol instances they reference. When you construct the Symbol, you can give it a string to be used as a description:

```
var isMoving = Symbol("isMoving");
```

When you `console.log()` such a Symbol, you'll see

```
Symbol(isMoving)
```

You can use `.toString()` to get the description, so if you wanted the description strings from all the Symbol properties:

```
var descrs = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(s => s.toString());
```

Comment: Exactly what `console.log()` shows may be browser-dependent, but the notion of the description is that it's visible for debugging so the console certainly *should* show it.

Comment: thank you @Pointy, could you please tell me too, how  I can get the names? (I don't want to get "Symbol(isMoving)", what currently no problem is, I would like to get the symbol property names als array (similar to Object.getOwnPropertyNames etc.)

Comment: @Lonely [Use `.toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30301728/1048572) for the symbol names and [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) for the list of symbols.

Comment: @Bergi Could you give me an example?

Comment: thank you, unfortunately there is no native solution, map + toString is not an elegant solution,..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Pointy and @Neall, symbols don't have names, but they can have descriptions.

Here's how you create a symbol with a description:

```js
const isMoving = Symbol('isMoving');
```

And here's how you access this description:

```js
console.log(isMoving.description); // Prints "isMoving"
```

The property `description` **isn't part of the official EcmaScript standard yet**. As of this writing, it is in Stage 3. So not every environment supports it. For details, see [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description).

Note that a symbol's description has nothing to do with the name of the variable holding it. Consider the following:

```js
const symbol1 = Symbol('Hello world!');
console.log(symbol1.description); // Prints "Hello world!", *not* "symbol1"

const symbol2 = symbol1;
console.log(symbol2.description); // Also prints "Hello world!"
```