# How does Symbol.keyFor() work?

Tags: ecmascript-6

For the below code,

```
let obj = {
    [Symbol('my_key')]: 1,
    enum: 2,
    nonEnum: 3
}

document.write(Symbol.keyFor(Symbol.for('my_key')) + '<br>'); //  retrieves 'my_key'
document.write(Symbol.keyFor(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)[0])); //  does not retrieve 'my_key'
```

below is the output:

```
my_key
undefined
```

---

Why `Symbol.keyFor()` does not retrieve token string in second case?

Comment: Related: [What is 'global symbol registry'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31897015/1048572) and [Get the description of a ES6 Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30301728/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/keyFor):

> The Symbol.keyFor(sym) method retrieves a shared symbol key from the global symbol registry for the given symbol.

In your first case you are using global symbol but as object key using local symbol:

```
// local symbol
Symbol('my_key')

// global symbol
Symbol.for('my_key')
```

When you use global symbol in your object literal it will work as youw expect:

```
let obj = {
    [Symbol.for('my_key')]: 1,
    enum: 2,
    nonEnum: 3
}
```

Global symbols are stored in global symbol registry. How do you store local symbols is up to you. Here is demonstrated the difference between the two:

```
Symbol('my_key') === Symbol('my_key') // false
Symbol.for('my_key') === Symbol.for('my_key') // true
```

Comment: `[Symbol.for('my_key')]: 1`. Is this creating new symbol in symbol registry instead of local call stack?

Comment: @overexchange yes, it will create when it does not exist.

Comment: When you say local symbol, you mean in scope of `window.obj`?

Comment: @overexchange local symbols are not stored in global symbol registry. You can store it in variable instead

Comment: Is `Symbol.iterator` a cross-realm symbol?